# DynamoDB ProvisionedReadCapacity exceeded

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, throughput

[image]I am load testing a service with 3000 requests per second. Each request fetches data from a DynamoDB table. The table has a provisioned read capacity of 10,000 reads per second. However, I am getting the following exception:

`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ProvisionedThroughputExceededException: The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceede
d. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ProvisionedThroughputE
xceededException; Request ID: KHOG5L1S83VU05CAOEJCCPAUFVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)`

My table description is as follows.

```
$ aws dynamodb describe-table --table-name my_table
{
"Table": {
    "TableArn": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:188456577:table/my_table", 
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
            "AttributeName": "username", 
            "AttributeType": "S"
        }
    ], 
    "ProvisionedThroughput": {
        "NumberOfDecreasesToday": 0, 
        "WriteCapacityUnits": 10000, 
        "LastIncreaseDateTime": 1462386432.633, 
        "ReadCapacityUnits": 10000
    }, 
    "TableSizeBytes": 289776, 
    "TableName": "my_table", 
    "TableStatus": "ACTIVE", 
    "KeySchema": [
        {
            "KeyType": "HASH", 
            "AttributeName": "username"
        }
    ], 
    "ItemCount": 81, 
    "CreationDateTime": 1458249331.208
    }
}
```

As can be seen, both read and write capacity units for the table have been set to 10,000.

I was monitoring the `health` of the beanstalk service while the load testing was in progress and the number of requests was indeed around 3K per second on an average. I don't understand why then the throughput capacity is exceeded. The table should also be getting 3,000 requests per second.

Comment: What do the [cloudwatch metrics](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/MonitoringDynamoDB.html#dynamodb-metrics) show?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have added the cloudwatch metric to the post. It shows that the consumed capacity is around 3,000 units, which is what I expected. Yet, I am getting those exceptions.

Comment: I would recommend reaching out to aws support

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot @Shibashis : are you aware of any way to throttle `AmazonDynamodbClient` so that it does not exceed the provisioned capacity? I checked `ClientConfiguration` but didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: There's not a way to do that, since you could have multiple clients all unaware of each other's requests.  The solution is catch the error, and [retry with exponential back-off](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html)... have you come up with an explanation of the limit you're hitting?  Does setting it to 5,000 cap you at 1,500, or do you still get 3,000?  What about setting it to 2,000?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DynamoDB does not throttle on the whole table capacity. From the documentation:

> The provisioned throughput associated with a table is also divided
>   evenly among the partitions, with no sharing of provisioned throughput
>   across partitions.

So if you have a read capacity of 10,000 per second and your table has say 10 partitions then each partition is allocated a read capacity of 1000 reads per second. If in your load test you are hitting keys in the same partition (uneven distribution of workload) then you will see ProvisionedThroughputExceededExceptions. You should try to have an even distribution of your partition key space so you can get the most of your provisioned throughput.

Read more on this topic [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html).

Comment: This explains why I see the exceptions even though I am apparently within the provisioned capacity. I am indeed using the same URL for each request from the load generators. Hence each request is pulling record for the same key. The partition handling that key is getting all the traffic. I'll try to vary the key during load test now.